# FormView in Twig lose submitted data when render the form

Tags: symfony, twig

I use the symfony 2.7.6 full stack framework.

When i submit a form, in the controller i get all submitted data, but in the view there is nothing, an empty form is rendered,something is wrong, i should display the submitted form with errors. but no data and no errors are shown in the twig form...

After hours of debuging of symfony, i can not resolve the problem.

Here is the form Type which is decalred as service:

```
<?php

namespace Skonsoft\ModelBundle\Form\Type;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolverInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\Storage\TokenStorageInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormEvent;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormEvents;
use Doctrine\Common\Persistence\ObjectManager;
use Skonsoft\UserBundle\Entity\User;

class ConversationType extends AbstractType
{
    /**
     * @var \Doctrine\Common\Persistence\ObjectManager
     */
    private $om;

    /**
     * @var TokenStorageInterface
     */
    protected $tokenStorage;

    /**
     * Constructor
     * 
     * @param ObjectManager $om
     * @param TokenStorageInterface $tokenStorage
     */
    public function __construct(ObjectManager $om,
                                TokenStorageInterface $tokenStorage)
    {
        $this->om = $om;
        $this->tokenStorage = $tokenStorage;
    }

    /**
     * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder
     * @param array $options
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
                ->add('message')
                ->add('advert', 'entity_hidden',
                      array(
                    'class' => 'SkonsoftModelBundle:Advert',
                    'data_class' => null,
                    'data' => $options['data']->getAdvert()
                ))
        ;

        $addUser = function(FormBuilderInterface $builder, User $user, $call) {
            $builder->addEventListener(FormEvents::PRE_SET_DATA,
                                       function(FormEvent $event) use ($user, $call) {
                $entity = $event->getData();
                $entity->$call($user);
            });
        };

        $from = $options['data']->getFrom();
        if (!$from) {
            $from = $this->om->getRepository('SkonsoftUserBundle:User')->find($this->tokenStorage->getToken()->getUser()->getId());
        }

        $to = $options['data']->getTo();
        if (!$to) {

            $advert = $this->om->getRepository('SkonsoftModelBundle:Advert')->find($options['data']->getAdvert());
            $to = $advert->getUser();
        }

        $addUser($builder, $from, 'setFrom');
        $addUser($builder, $to, 'setTo');
    }

    /**
     * @param OptionsResolverInterface $resolver
     */
    public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'Skonsoft\ModelBundle\Entity\Conversation'
        ));
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getName()
    {
        return 'ss_conversation';
    }

}
```

An this is the controller action:

```
/**
 * Creates a new Conversation entity.
 *
 * @Route("/{id}", name="conversation_create")
 * @Method("POST")
 * @ParamConverter("advert", class="SkonsoftModelBundle:Advert")
 * @Template("SkonsoftUserBundle:Conversation:new.html.twig")
 */
public function createAction(Request $request, Advert $advert)
{
    $entity = new Conversation();
    $entity->setAdvert($advert);
    $form = $this->createCreateForm($entity);
    $form->handleRequest($request);

    $t = $this->get('translator');

    if ($form->isValid()) {
        $manager = $this->get('skonsoft_model.conversation_manager');
        $manager->persist($entity);

        $this->addFlash('success', $t->trans('message.send.success'));

        return $this->redirect($request->headers->get('referer'));
    }

    $this->addFlash('danger', $t->trans('message.send.error'));

    return array(
        'entity' => $entity,
        'form' => $form->createView(),
    );
}

 /**
 * Creates a form to create a Conversation entity.
 *
 * @param Conversation $entity The entity
 *
 * @return \Symfony\Component\Form\Form The form
 */
private function createCreateForm(Conversation $entity)
{
    $form = $this->createForm('ss_conversation', $entity);

    return $form;
}
```

and this is the twig:

```
{{form_start(form, {'action': path('conversation_create', {'id': entity.advert.id}), 'method': 'POST', 'class':'form-horizontal', 'role':'form' } )}}

<div class="form-group row">
    <div class="col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
        {{ form_widget(form.message, {'attr': {'class': 'form-control pull-right', 'placeholder':"message.text_holder" | trans, 'rows':'6' } }) }}
    </div>

    <div class="widget_error  col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
        {{ form_errors(form.message) }}
    </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group row">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-lg {{'css.pull.right'|trans}}">{{ "Send" | trans }} </button>
</div>

{{form_end(form)}}
```

When i dump the FormView in the controller, i get the submitted data and their errors... but not in the wiew

Any Body has any idea what's wrong ?

Thank you

Comment: In your view, have you tried rendering the whole form using just `{{ form(form) }}` rather than with your markup? I've had issues with error bubbling and display before that may explain your issues. If the errors display when doing `{{ form(form) }}` then that might be it.

Comment: it was not an error, just a mistake that i made by using the render_esi helper, so i lost all submitted data. Take a look at my answer above.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry, it was my mistake, not related to symfony.

So, here is the problem:
With this configuration, everything works fine, just i used the **render_esi** helper to render the form and i forget that render_esi is a new request to make, so when i submit the form, **first master request** get and process the form, but i **lose all form's data after calling the render_esi** helper.